# Anime about a boy and a girl who ride ostrich-like creatures through a valley

Tags: story-identification, anime

I can not remember much but I have had this film in my head for years I searched everything I can remember on every website I can think of.

I don't remember the exact story but I'll list everything about it can

- Apocalyptic future possibly
- Two main characters: a boy and a girl riding ostrich-like creatures through a valley
- An old blind lady that senses things
- Crashed spaceship looking like a submarine
- Giant creatures looks like yaks with blue eyes, whose eyes turn red when something is about to happen
- The old lady says "Some say they went to the stars" while looking at the spaceship
- The two main characters do something and their eyes turn blue in the distance and the village cheers

This film is at least ten years old and I would appreciate it so much if you knew anything about it, or could help me find the title.

Comment: I immediately thought of the Disney movie _Swiss Family Robinson_ where the strabded kids rode on actual ostriches.

Answer (score 31):

This is [Nausicaa of the Valley of the Wind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nausica%C3%A4_of_the_Valley_of_the_Wind_%28film%29).

The giant creatures with the red eyes and the submarine in the desert are a dead giveaway,.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you all so much, you have solved the mystery <3

Comment: @HarryStarling - Don't forget to upvote and press the accepted button.