# A sci fi animated movie about time travel. It has some weird looking slug like creatures

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, animated-series

This was an animated science fiction move. I remember that it has some (slug-like) creatures and the movie is about time travel.

Comment: Not a lot to go on here. Can you have a look through the checklists here and see if you can come up with some more detail? https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question

Comment: More specifically, can you tell us when you watched it. What was the style of the animation? Was it in black and white or colour? What language was it in? Who were the protagonists / main characters? What ages were the characters? How did people travel in time? Was there a device or was it via some other method? What did the slug-like creatures look like (big/small/colourful/etc)? Was there a plot? Was there a villain?

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/79745/anime-about-a-boy-and-a-girl-who-ride-ostrich-like-creatures-through-a-valley