# Anime Identification - Female mage bitten by small creature

Tags: story-identification, anime

(Anywhere that text is italicised indicates my uncertainty to the claims veracity)

I'm searching for an anime (Japanese-style animation) movie/series (although it felt more like a feature film), that I remember watching a portion of before 2006 (Most likely watched it on mainstream television in 2005 or 2004).

I'm unsure whether it was dubbed or not. I think it was a relatively modern anime (appeared to use computer-based shading and dynamic lighting effects (and CGI)). In the small segment that I remember, a Woman/Girl is bitten on the finger (or hand) by a small creature, and her finger begins to bleed (I think there was a shot focusing on the blood slowly forming a pool on her finger). The woman was either holding the creature at the time, or had reached out to pet it, and had ended up being bitten. *I think that the creature jumps and remains on the shoulder of the woman after they become friendly with one another.* The particular setting of this scene was on a habitable planet (Unaware if it was earth), in the daytime with a blue sky and some clouds. *In the background of the scene, were tall structures, possibly wind turbines.* *I think the genre was science fantasy and magic may have been an in-universe occurrence ( I think the woman themselves was a magic user).*

**Description of Creature:**

*-Similar to design of Filli from Deltora Quest anime*

*-Reminiscent of the design of non-evolved Digimon monsters (first series)*

**Description of Woman/Girl:**

*-Orange/light brown hair*

-Light skin

(EDIT: Having now watched Nausicaa in response to McTroopers answer, I was surprised at how similar it was to my description, however it didn't seem to be what I was searching for. I think the Woman had larger eyes than Princess Nausicaa, a size more in line with 90's or 00's era anime. Nausicaa, although this might be influenced by my own rose-tinted glasses, seemed to have a more muted colour aesthetic than the anime I remember (it seeming to have brightness/lighting only achievable by computer-based shading et cetera))

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/79745/anime-about-a-boy-and-a-girl-who-ride-ostrich-like-creatures-through-a-valley

Comment: @BoogaRoo  (1) No (2) Unsure (I'd lean more to creature being unique to Woman character). (3) Unsure (4) Tone probably felt like adventure (Woman may have been part of a band of people that was on a quest for something which I can't recollect) (5) Unsure (6) I'd say 50/50 fusion of science and magic, (although I don't know if in-universe magic was justified as advanced science, or both were treated as independent systems).

Answer (score 25):

Sounds like a scene from [Nausicaa of the Valley of the Wind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nausica%C3%A4_of_the_Valley_of_the_Wind_(film)), one of the first animated movies by Myazaki.
Of course it is not very recent (early 80s) and I don't think it featured any CGI, even if the drawings and animations were of very good quality for the period.

The scene you saw happened at the beginning of the movie: the animal is a [fox-squirrel](https://nausicaa.fandom.com/wiki/Fox-squirrels) (that had been found by a friend of Nausicaa's), who bites Nausicaa beacuse it is frightened. She doesn't react to the bite in order for it to calm itself, then began friend with her.
[image]

The setting is a post-apocalyptic future, which features huge ruins of the previous era, and also wind mills built by the survivors
[image]

Comment: This was also literally my first thought based on the description. And while magic isn't really a thing in this setting, Nausicaä could easily be mistaken for a 'mage' in that she regularly does things that people think are borderline impossible (overall there's a very strong 'chosen one' trope going on throughout the whole series (both the original manga and the movie) centered around Nausicaä).